# Why do I always get NULL in JSF fetching postgresql boolean field?

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf, jpa, boolean

I have Postgresql 8.4 table

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  username character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  "password" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  enabled boolean NOT NULL,
  type_of_signature boolean NOT NULL,
  companyusers2_id integer NOT NULL,
  numberorganizac character(8) NOT NULL,
);
```

In that table i have just one row: ""admin";"admin";TRUE;TRUE;1;"12345678"

I have JPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users implements Serializable {
    ...
    private boolean typeOfSignature;
    ...

    @Column(name="type_of_signature")
    public boolean getTypeOfSignature() {
        return this.typeOfSignature;
    }

    public void setTypeOfSignature(boolean typeOfSignature) {
        this.typeOfSignature = typeOfSignature;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have JSF

```
<h:outputText value="Type of signature is NULL" rendered="#{curUser.typeOfSignature == null}"/>
<h:outputText value="Type of Signature is TRUE" rendered="#{curUser.typeOfSignature}"/>
<h:outputText value="Type of Signature is FALSE" rendered="#{!curUser.typeOfSignature}"/>
```

I always get "Type of signature is NULLType of Signature is FALSE" at result page.

But I also have method in my bean

```
if(getCurUser().getTypeOfSignature())
    {
        jpaBean.pushSignature(dataItem, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        jpaBean.pushSignature(dataItem, 2);
    }
```

And it works right depending on type of user's signature.

Why I always get NULL in JSF? Or I'm a newby and have done something wrong?

Comment: I don't know JSF, but I do see that your field is a `boolean`, not a `Boolean`. `getCurUser().getTypeOfSignature() == null` would be a compilation error in Java. Is this just how JSF handles the error case?

Comment: I've tried `Boolean` and `boolean`. Both variants make the same result **Type of signature is NULLType of Signature is FALSE**

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should use `#{BEAN_NAME.curUser.typeOfSignature}`

Comment: @Adrian, I believe this wouldn't be a compilation error because of the Autoboxing feature.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing

Comment: @maple_shaft, According to a quick test in Eclipse, `The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, null`. Auto unboxing will promote a `boolean` to a `Boolean` in a function parameter, but won't allow a comparison with null.

Comment: Can you try to annotate the field, not the get method?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue before when trying to use Boolean type with JPA and JSF, 
you can try to create a Custom BooleanConverter and map your JPA Entity with a Boolean instead of the raw type boolean.

Even though you might run into portability issues as you run this with different DBs, JSF and JPA implementations. I strongly suggest you change your approach to map Booleans as Strings in JPA:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  username character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  "password" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  enabled haracter(1) NULL,
  type_of_signature char(1) NOT NULL,
  companyusers2_id integer NOT NULL,
  numberorganizac character(8) NOT NULL,
);
```

and your mapping would turn to be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users implements Serializable {
    ...
    private String typeOfSignature;
    ...

    @Column(name="type_of_signature")
    public String getTypeOfSignature() {
        return this.typeOfSignature;
    }

    public void setTypeOfSignature(String typeOfSignature) {
        this.typeOfSignature = typeOfSignature;
    }
    ...
}
```

populate your record with one row: ""admin";"admin";'T';'T';1;"12345678"
then in JSF you shall have a different result:

```
<h:outputText value="Type of signature is NULL" rendered="#{empty curUser.typeOfSignature}"/>
<h:outputText value="Type of Signature is TRUE" rendered="#{curUser.typeOfSignature eq 'T'}"/>
<h:outputText value="Type of Signature is FALSE" rendered="#{!curUser.typeOfSignature eq 'T'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<h:outputText value="Type of signature is True" rendered="#{true}"/>
<h:outputText value="Type of signature is False" rendered="#{false}"/>
```

?

If these fails that means that something is wrong with value binder. It should not be for basic html elements.

```
import javax.faces.component.ActionSource;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.ValueHolder;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.el.ValueBinding;


public class MyHtmlOutputText extends HtmlOutputText {

    public boolean isRendered() {
        if (rendered != null) {
            return rendered;
        }

        ValueBinding vb = getValueBinding("rendered");
        Boolean v = vb != null ? (Boolean) vb.getValue(getFacesContext()) : null;
        return v != null ? v : DEFAULT_DISABLED;
    }

    public boolean getRendered() {
        return isRendered();
    }

}
```

For some reason I do not store the result of value binding. That reason is because the value  stored into state and will be no longer resolved from original expression in a runtime. That's what we definitively don't want to have.

There you will find how to register your `MyHtmlOutputText` component into facelets context: http://hanzz.lbs-logics.at/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=107&Itemid=31